# Nginx post-ssl-termination debug mirror

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, tcpdump

How can I tell nginx to output all incoming traffic for a given `server{}` to a specific/additional/redundant location *after* decrypting it (like [port mirroring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) on routers) so that it can be analyzed for troubleshooting purposes?

I need to debug the traffic coming-in to an https-only website. The server is headless, and I'd rather

1. Not install a GUI just for wireshark
2. Not move my private keys off the server for later analysis on my local GUI with wireshark

So wireshark (the most commonly-cited solution for decrypting an https stream) is not a solution. I want something that's CLI-only and requires minimal tools done live on the server. I checked `tcpdump`'s https support; it's absent but you can combine a ton of other tools and get it functional, but it's not exactly ideal.

My web server is nginx. I'm wondering if there's some way to setup nginx such that--in addition to the way it normally handles its traffic for a given `server{}` block--send the decrypted traffic to some mirror (just for debugging) that I can then analyze directly with `tcpdump`, ideally in real-time.

Is it possible to add a `proxy_pass` mirror to an nginx `server{}` block such that nginx handles the traffic as it usually does *plus* sending the decrypted traffic to some "debug" location (which could just be an `nc -l 8080` or something)?

Comment: You can load a capture from tcpdump into wireshark.

Comment: I don't think you read my question.

Comment: I read every word of it.

Comment: [1] I said the traffic is encrypted [2] I said I don't want to install wireshark on the (headless)  server [3] for security reasons, I said I don't want to move the private keys off the server [4] I literally said "So wireshark...is not a solution"

Comment: Nobody said anything about installing Wireshark on the server. But no, nginx doesn't do that. It's a web server. Your switch might, though. You still have the problem of decrypting the data, if you really want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I found out recently that nginx does indeed have this functionality beginning with version 1.13.4. Using the `mirror` directive you can forward a copy of each request to a different HTTP server. The response, if any, is ignored.

In the `server` or `location` for which you want requests mirrored, add a `mirror` directive with a URL path that will never occur on your web site. Then, add a new `location` that serves exactly that path and passes the requests to some other server.

A simplistic example:

```
server {
    location / {
        mirror /Jahg3bioshes;
        # ... the rest of your directives
    }

    location = /Jahg3bioshes {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://sink.server.example$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Note that while nginx ignores the response, it does not ignore the time taken to serve the response, and if the mirror server is slow to respond, it will also slow down the original request. It should probably just be some trivial server, e.g. a freshly installed web server with the distribution default configuration.

Comment: nice. Is the request sent to the server defined by `proxy_pass` above decrypted? Is it possible to make this destination server just a simple `netcat` "server" or anything just as easy for a quick `tcpdump`?

Comment: And is it possible to set a super-low timeout on the mirror's destination "server" so that it can't harm the production traffic?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield It's only decrypted if you specify http. If you specify https it will be re-encrypted. And you need to run a real web server at the other end, as nginx will wait for an actual HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

nginx support lua as a scripting language. So you can write your own functions to manipulate and save data by calling ngx.var.request_body and  ngx.var.echo_request_body, or use the one which already there, for example https://github.com/thinkinside-LQ/httpdump

Comment: This could work. Of course lua is not in nginx itself, it requires a third party build like openresty.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I've already solved a number of problems with nginx lua, eg. logging a response body, without the use of openresty.  On my devuan installations I have only libnginx-mod-http-lua.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille That _is_ the openresty/lua module. Debian bundles it with nginx without making it clear that it's a third party module.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I didn't know Debian was in the habit of doing that.  I checked if I didn't install a non-free package without knowing, but they've incorporated it in their version of the nginx source package.  According to a README, a number of things can go wrong or are not as optimized as when you would use the openresty Nginx.  Still, this is a package built by Debian maintainers, isn't it?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Debian does a lot of bizarre stuff. This one doesn't even move the meter that much. They bundle a bunch of other third party modules and install it as `nginx-extras`; this is hardly the only one. Nevertheless this one is under a BSD license, so it counts as free. Part of the issue is that until a few years ago nginx did not support dynamic module loading, so you had to compile nginx and modules together. That's no longer necessary, but they also haven't unbundled the modules either...

Comment: The nginx itself has BSD like license.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing what you want. Either by using SSLKEYLOG and tshark, or by installing a reverse TLS proxy.

### OPTION 1: SSLKEYLOG + TSHARK

The first option would be to log the SSL master secrets to an [SSLKEYLOGFILE](https://github.com/tiandrey/nginx-sslkeylog), capture the encrypted traffic with tcpdump and analyze it with tshark (the command line version of Wireshark).

### OPTION 2: REVERSE TLS PROXY

The second option would be to install a TLS inspection proxy that supports "Reverse Proxy" mode, which decrypts incoming traffic and then re-encrypts it before forwarding it to the web server. The proxy must also support sending a copy of the traffic in DECRYPTED mode to an external interface somehow.

You might be able to do "OPTION 2" with [SSLsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit), but I'm not sure. I do know that you can do it with [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) though (disclaimer: PolarProxy is developed by us at Netresec). We have a blog post called [Reverse Proxy and TLS Termination](https://netresec.com/?b=2033d38) that explains how to set up the reverse proxy. You can then use [tcpreplay](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpreplay) to push the decrypted traffic to a network interface.